# Evaluating: $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{x-\sin x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I was asked to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{x-\sin x}$$

I really have no idea how to solve it!

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: @5xum up vote it please

Comment: The only way you can "have no idea" how to solve it is if you didn't even try to solve it. No upvote from me, sorry. Look in the book where you got the task, find similar limits and how they were evaluated, and try to apply the same methods.

Comment: I will recommend you to search about L' Hospital Rule

Comment: @5xum I'm a high school student! My teacher gave us this question and it isn't from our curriculum! I have to ask people who are older and more educated than me! Any way thank you

Comment: You should ask your teacher for some hints. If your teacher expects you to solve things beyond curriculum, you should expect your teacher to teach some stuff beyond curriculum.

Comment: This limit goes to 0. I don't think the result is 3. see below

Comment: Why does peoples downted this post?

Comment: @GuyFsone: probably because it lacks any attempt from the OP. *Not enough context*, and I agree.

Comment: Yes but clearly it is easy here to provide an attempt. especially if the OP just started learning Taylor expansion

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor of oder 4, [near $x= 0$ see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)  we have 
$$\sin x\sim x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^4)~~~and ~~~~\tan x\sim x +\frac{x^3}{3} +o(x^4)$$ 
but $\tan x\sim x+\frac{x^3}{3}$ stay near 0 as x is near 0 therefore, 
$$\sin(\tan x) \sim \sin(x+\frac{x^3}{3}) \sim x+\frac{x^3}{3}  -\frac{1}{6}(x+\frac{x^3}{3})^3 = x+ \frac{x^3}{6}  +o(x^4)$$

similarly, $\sin x\sim x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ stay near 0 as x is near 0 therfore,

$$\tan(\sin x) \sim  x-\frac{x^3}{6}  +\frac{1}{3}(x-\frac{x^3}{6})^3 \sim x+\frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^4)$$

also 
$$x-\sin x  \sim \frac{1}{6}x^3 +o(x^4)$$
we conclude that

$$\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{x-\sin x}\sim \frac{x+\frac{x^3}{6}-x-\frac{x^3}{6} +o(x^4)}{\frac{x^3}{6} +o(x^4) } = \frac{0+o(x)}{\frac{1}{6} +o(x) }$$

that is $$\color{red}{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{x-\sin x} = 0}.$$

**OR By L'hopital rule** 
we have 
 $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{x-\sin x} \\ = 
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+\tan^2x)\cos(\tan x)-\cos x(1+\tan^2(\sin x))}{1-\cos x} \sim \frac{0+o(x^2)}{\frac{x^2}{2} +o(x^2)} = 0 $$
by just taking Taylor of oder 2 to get the same answer.

Comment: Everything is in its right place now. $\sin\tan x-\tan\sin x$ behaves like $-\frac{x^7}{30}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, hence the wanted limit is $0$, not $3$.

Comment: Yes at the first time I used two different oder in the same limit. So I lost some term while applying the first oder.